# Proper way to track progress or levels in a web application database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website based upon achievements and the achievements are categorized into 50+ groups. Each group has 500 achievements. Upon completion of an achievement I make a record in the database with the date in which they completed it. I always track each groups progress individually as well as overall. For instance:

```
Group 1: 5/500
Group 2: 89/500
Group 3: 21/654
Overall: 115/1654
```

My question, is it a bad practice to compute these progress reports from scratch all the time or should I have another table that stores these progress and I update it every now and then?

Answer (score 1):

Create an activity table which tracks the individual achievements and compute them all the time. The beauty with this is if you change the way you compute achivements then you do not need to touch your raw data at all

If this becomes too slow then you can create an achievements tracking table that you compute the achievements and store them on a regular basis for querying purposes.

Comment: Meaning computing it on the spot all the time?

Comment: Initially you can compute it on the spot all the time. However if this slows down then you can compute it say every day and save the results of the computation in a separate table that you can use to show the progress reports

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to know if you should [Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_caching) your output or not. That really depends on your application.

- Is it a product that is to be deployed multiple times "as is"? Implement caching.
- Otherwise, do you have performance issues with the reports?

  - *No*? Don't cache.
  - *Yes*? Implement caching.

There are various strategies for caching, for your kind of application (I just assume here that you have a collection of multiple 'objects' that can get those achievements) I would prefer caches that invalidate on certain events. Like whenever object x gets an achievement, this "event" invalidates the cache.

The output code queries the cache first, and only if that is invalid executes code that rebuilds it. This ensures that the output is always valid as opposed to rebuilding all caches every x hours.